# How to avoid deep copy with std::vector of boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, stdvector

I have written a simple template that takes as input a [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) and stores message pointers in a std::vector using the cpp [api](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API).

```
template <class M>
class LocalizedMessageCollector
{
  void processBag(const rosbag::Bag& bag, const std::vector<std::string>& topics)
  {
    // create bag view
    rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));
    
    BOOST_FOREACH (rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
    {
       ...

       boost::shared_ptr<M const> msg = m.instantiate<M>();
       msgCallback(msg);
       
       ...
  
    }
  }

  void msgCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<M const>& msg)
  {
   
    ...

    dataset_.push_back(std::make_pair(pose, msg));
  }


  std::vector<std::pair<tf2::Transform, boost::shared_ptr<M const>>> dataset_;
}
```

Unfortunately this code consumes an incredible amount of memory. I suspect that the push_back call is actually performing a deep copy, because:

- as it is, the code consumes my 32GB of RAM after few seconds
- if I comment the push_back line, I don't have this problem

My intention was to avoid deep copy and just store in the vector pointers to the messages. Can please someone point out what I'm doing wrong and explain me how to do properly what I'd like to do?

Thanks.

Comment: "*My intention was to ... just store in the vector pointers to the messages*" - that is exactly what you are doing. You are creating `M` objects in dynamic memory and passing around pointers to them. However, have you tried making your `BOOST_FOREACH` loop use *references* to the `view` elements? Your loop is taking the elements by *value*, so you are making a deep copy of each element before you have a chance to call `instantiate()` on it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for the suggestion. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no "deep copy" of `shared_ptr`, by definition. A vector reallocation won't even juggle reference counts, as move semantics should be employed for the shared_ptr. However, whatever `tf2::Transform` is, that's going to be a different story, on its own merits.

Comment: @FedericoNardi `BOOST_FOREACH (rosbag::MessageInstance const &m, view)` Note the `&`, just like in the parameters of your functions.

Comment: Only the pointer is copied. Perhaps the memory leak is because you are pushing way too many messages?

Comment: *"if I comment the push_back line, I don't have this problem"* -- Sure, not saving data can reduce your memory footprint. What makes you think this is a case of a deep copy instead of a case of the vector having the only copy? (The code you've shown is inconclusive on this because you appropriately trimmed it down.) Are the messages stored somewhere else, which would let you see if a change to one is reflected in the other?